# How to include proxy configuration for npm module client-oauth2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, proxy, oauth2client

```
const ClientOAuth2 = require('client-oauth2');

const oauth2 = new ClientOAuth2({
    clientId: 'clientId',
    clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
    accessTokenUri: 'https://fakeurl.com/v1/auth/token',
});

oauth2 .credentials.getToken().then(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Is there a way i can include proxy settings when requesting for a token given i am running this code inside a corporate network

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look and couldn't find an easy way to do it. Other than proxy features I noticed also that it is missing Open Id Connect features such as these:

- Looking up metadata
- Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Calls to the User Info Endpoint

**REQUIREMENTS**

Choosing a library for your apps is an important decision, and here are a few common things people usually look for:

- Standards Based (works for any Authorization Server)
- Certified as following the latest OAuth 2.1 and Open Id Connect recommendations
- Supports HTTP proxying (highly useful to view OAuth messages when developing)

**NODEJS SOLUTION**

If you are using Node it might be worth considering the [node openid-client](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) library, which is the one I use. Here is some relevant code from an API of mine:

- [Looking up metadata](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/issuerMetadata.ts) - note that an agent can be supplied to support proxying
- [Setting the HTTP proxy](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/utilities/httpProxy.ts) - I use TunnelAgent.httpsOverHttp to proxy calls to HTTPS OAuth URLs
- [OAuth Operations](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/oauthAuthenticator.ts) - note that there are some custom classes that make these tasks easier